Function with complicated argument constraint with default value
I need to define a function, say f with an argument which is integer, positive and with a default value say 2. I tried:
f[n_Integer?Positive:2]:=n^4-3*n+5

or
f[n_Integer:2?Positive]:=n^4-3*n+5

but it didn't work.

Sorry, I don't see any parameter here: n is the argument of f.

In this case, the first : which is the shorthand of Pattern cannot be omitted (yeah n_ is actually a shorthand of n : _):
f[n : _Integer?Positive : 2] := n^4 - 3 n + 5

